# Neo4jrb Neo4j::Session::CypherError: uuid not defined

Tags: ruby, neo4j.rb

i try to create a custom getOrCreate method using find and if nothing is returned using create

my class :

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4jrbConcern

  property :name
  property :email

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true
end
```

the method getOrCreate inherited from the concern

```
def getOrCreate(params)
  obj = self.find(params)
  if obj
    puts 'obj found : ' + obj
    return obj
  else
    return self.create(params)
  end
end
```

i'm trying this :

```
User.getOrCreate(
   name: data['name'],
   email: data['email']
)
```

the result is this error :

```
Neo4j::Session::CypherError: uuid not defined (line 1, column 86)
"MATCH (result_user:`User`) WHERE result_user.uuid.name = {result_user_uuid_name} AND uuid.email = {result_user_uuid_email} RETURN result_user ORDER BY ID(result_user) LIMIT {limit_1}"
                                                                                      ^
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.0/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:166:in `raise_cypher_error'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.0/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:164:in `response'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.0/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:205:in `pluck'
```

do you see what i did wrong ?

thanks !

Benoît

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a hash into `find` like that.  It should be something like:

```
def getOrCreate(params)
  obj = self.where(params).first
  if obj
    puts 'obj found : ' + obj
    return obj
  else
    return self.create(params)
  end
end
```

Though this also seems like the perfect case for using a cypher `MERGE` which means you'd only need to do one query.

Comment: @brian-unserwood 
thanks, i was lost in the doc.

how would the code look like for a merge ?
i'm trying this but i can't figure out how to return an object :
`
      query = Neo4j::Session.query
              .merge(q: {self.name => params})
      obj = query.return(:q).to_a
`

Comment: Yeah,that's close.  `Neo4j::Session.query.merge(var: {ClassName: params}).pluck(:var).first`

Comment: Yours seems like it should work pretty well, what was the problem?

Comment: Yes, that was fine, thanks. i ended up with that :
Neo4j::Session.query.merge(q: {self.name.to_sym => {uuid: uuid}}).on_create_set(q: params).pluck(:q).first